# What is $E(X\mid X>c)$ in terms of $P(X>c)$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> What is $E(X\mid X>c)$ in terms of $P(X>c)$?

I've seen conditional probability/expectation before with respect to another random variable but not to the variable itself. How would I go about interpreting this?

Comment: As a simple example, suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable taking on values $0$, $1$, $2$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{3}$.  Then, _conditioned_ on $X > 0$, $X$ can take on values $1$ or $2$ with probability $$P\{X = i\mid X > 0\} = \frac{P(\{X = i\}\cap \{X > 0\})}{P\{X > 0\}} = \frac{P\{X = i\}}{P\{X > 0\}} = \frac{1/3}{2/3} = \frac{1}{2}, i = 1, 2$$ and so $$E[X\mid X > 0]= \frac{1}{2}\times[1 + 2] = \frac{3}{2}$$.

Answer (score 9):

$$
\mathrm E(X\mid X\gt c)=\frac{\mathrm E(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X\gt c})}{\mathrm P(X\gt c)}
$$

Comment: Could you please clarify what the conditional density function and conditional cumulative distribution would be for this case?

Comment: @user249613 If you have a new problem, you might want to post it as a new question. If you do so, adding your thoughts on the subject would be mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

@Dilip has already provided an example of how to *compute* $E(X|X>c)$ in the discrete case. In the continuous case, the computation will be:

$$E(X|X>c) = \frac{\int_x x f(x) I(x>c) dx}{\int_x f(x) I(x>c) dx}$$

Thus, if we let $X \sim U[0,1]$ and $c=0.5$ then we have:

$$E(X|X>0.5) = \frac{\int_x x  I(x>0.5) dx}{\int_x  I(x>0.5) dx} = \frac{(1 - 0.5^2)/2}{0.5}=0.75$$

In terms of interpretation: Intuitively, you can think of $E(X|X>c)$ as the *average* of all $X$ values subject to each one of them being greater than $c$.