# Understanding formulas for $E(X∣X < c)$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I have $E(X∣X < c)$ where $X$ is a continuous random variable and $c$ is a given positive real value.

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483001/how-to-find-conditional-expectation-and-variance) this is equivalent to:

1. $E[X|X<c]=\int_{-\inf}^{c}1-\frac{F(x)}{F(c)}dx$

On this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89459/what-is-ex-mid-xc-in-terms-of-pxc/89479?newreg=9fb3bbb386784293b71bb1b62b356c4d) we have both:

2. $\mathrm E(X\mid X < c)=\frac{\mathrm E(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X < c})}{\mathrm P(X\gt c)}$
3. $E(X|X<c) = \frac{\int_x x f(x) I(x<c) dx}{\int_x f(x) I(x<c) dx}$

Yet, starting from the definition of conditional expectation, I couldn't get to show any of the three equations.
I am particularly interested in the first one.

Can you help me understand how to get it? (And or the others)

Thanks.

Comment: The first one looks almost right when you integrate by parts.  The third one is a roundabout way of integrating from$-\infty$ to $c$ for both the the numerator and the denominator.  The second seems to have an error for the denominator.

Comment: Ps.  Ensure that you use the definition for expectation conditioned over an *event,* rather than a random variable.